# Cypher - Adding relationships between nodes and add the nodes if they do not exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to perform the following Cypher query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE (
event:Event { 
    id : '94ECE7BE-882C-446B-94FE-9348E0DF5E08', 
    startTimestamp : 1370821057.000000, 
    endTimestamp : 1370907457.000000, 
    type : 2, 
    category : 1,
    privacy : 1,
    dressCode : 4 
}), 
event<-[:CREATOR]-(creator:User { 
    id : '55A1CA51-9489-41E1-8083-EC23E974E604', 
    type : 1, 
    email : 'something@gmail.com' 
});
```

Except all I get is the somewhat annoying error message:

```
Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to cypher@neo4j.org.
```

What is the issue with this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create unique` needs a relationship to anchor your pattern. I'm assuming for performance reasons, as verifying that no node in the DB matches the ones in the query would be problematic. Also, your query creates a new User node in each execution, which is probably not what you want.

If you have existing creator nodes (e.g. only known users can add events), you can use that as a starting point:

```
match creator:User where creator.id='unique' 
CREATE UNIQUE (
event:Event { 
    id : '94ECE7BE-882C-446B-94FE-9348E0DF5E08', 
    startTimestamp : 1370821057.000000, 
    endTimestamp : 1370907457.000000, 
    type : 2, 
    category : 1,
    privacy : 1,
    dressCode : 4 
})<-[:CREATOR]-(creator)
```

The next 2.0 milestone will probably add unique constraints on types.

If you do want to create new `creator` nodes, one workaround is to attach all events to a dedicated anchor, but that will give you a dense node that will slowdown the queries over time:

```
start n=node(0) CREATE UNIQUE n-[r:FOO]- (
event:Event { 
    id : '94ECE7BE-882C-446B-94FE-9348E0DF5E08', 
    startTimestamp : 1370821057.000000, 
    endTimestamp : 1370907457.000000, 
    type : 2, 
    category : 1,
    privacy : 1,
    dressCode : 4 
})<-[:CREATOR]-(creator:User { 
    id : '55A1CA51-9489-41E1-8083-EC23E974E604', 
    type : 1, 
    email : 'something@gmail.com' 
}) return event, creator
```

So better don't do that.

Comment: Yeah, I initially tried the first way but wanted to create something a little more polymorphic for objects which inherit from others. Looks like I'll have to stick with this. Do we know when the next milestone will come out?